# .pluck function in strongloop loopback?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

Does storongloop loopback has pluck function for a given model ?

For a Product model,

in Rails I can write

`Product.where(some_condition).pluck(:name)`

It will return an array of names of products matching the condition.

Is there anything similar in loopback?

PS: I know I can use `fields` filter and then use underscore( or lodash)'s pluck but that's a two step process.

Answer (score 1):

Select specific columns:

```
{"fields":{"name":true, "email":true}}
```

Where condition:

```
{"where":{"id":2}}
```

Combining:

```
{"fields":{"id":true},"where":{"id":{"inq":[10,20,30]}}}
```

The above code works in swagger. **Node.js**  code would be as follows:

```
var m = server.models.customer;
    m.findOne({
        fields: ['name', 'email'],
        where: {
            id:{inq:[10,20,30]}}
        }
    }, function (err, data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
```

Comment: That's what I mentioned in PS that I can use fields filter and then use underscore's pluck (to convert hash into an array)

The reason why we need an array is if I want to run `inq` query on the ids returned by first query, i ll need any array of ids. 

Databases are good (and designed to be good) with handling large amount of data. Rails has this functionality built in. That is why I was wondering if loopback has the same.

Comment: I've changed the query to meet your requirement. This is converted to single sql query behind the scene. So it'll be one step process. You can see that in any profiler if avialable.